# Puppeteer-web: Protocol error (Target: getBrowserContexts) not allowed

Tags: puppeteer

I've got a chrome extension that is trying to implement puppeteer-web. I've followed the following code to try and get set up
[puppeteer-web: "Puppeteer is not a constructor"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53001009/puppeteer-web-puppeteer-is-not-a-constructor/53024164#53024164)

This is my code:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
async function initiatePuppeteer() {
  let browserWSEndpoint = '';
  await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:9222/json")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(function(data) {
        let filteredData = data.filter(tab => tab.type ==='page');
        browserWSEndpoint = filteredData[0].webSocketDebuggerUrl;
      })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
    const browser = await puppeteer.connect({
      browserWSEndpoint: browserWSEndpoint
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    ....etc
}
```

It doesn't seem the code makes it past this point as when I put a debugger at `const browser = await puppeteer.connect` I get the error

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Protocol error (Target.getBrowserContexts): Not allowed.
```

Using Chrome version V76.0.3809.100
Any ideas?

Edit: my webSocketDebuggerUrl is something like `ws://127.0.0.1:9222/devtools/page/E1B62B356262B00C26A5D79D03745360`

And I suspect it's because it's `/page/` and not `/browser/` but I couldn't find any of type browser from the /json route. I'll give it another look at it tonight.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok so it turns out puppeteer can only connect to a `browser` target and not a `page` target as per https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/4579#issuecomment-511267351

And reading the documentation for the API (which I should have done earlier...) https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#browserwsendpoint states that URL for the `browser` target is `http://${host}:${port}/json/version` instead of just `/json`